# Difference of numpy arrays of different dimensions

Tags: numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

Say I have two 2D arrays `A` and `B` with shape: `(10, 10)` and `(3, 3)` respectively.

I would like to know if there is a way to compute `A - B` such that the shape is: `(10, 10, 9)` without using a loop.

i.e, difference of each element of `A` with every element from `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use outer subtraction and then reshape -

```
np.subtract.outer(A,B).reshape((A.shape)+(-1,))
```

Or extend `A` to `3D` with a singleton dim as the last one and subtract flattend `B` -

```
A[...,None] - B.ravel() # or B.flat in place of B.ravel()
```

Comment: Or `np.subtract.outer(A, B.ravel())` --- not trolling btw. just not enough added value for a separate answer